# How can i create an array user meta?

Tags: users, user-meta

I want to create a new user meta that contains array content
How can i do this ?

Another question :
is it true using this code to check if the **array** user meta exists before creating it ?

```
<?php
$key = 'add_me';
$user_id= get_current_user_id();
$themeta = get_user_meta($user_id , $key, TRUE);
if($themeta != '') {
// code 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted at the codex page for [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta):

> **NOTE**
>       If the meta value does not exist and $single is true the function will return an empty string. If $single is false an empty array is returned.

So I would suggest to do the check like this:

```
! empty( $themeta )
```

Regrading your other question, you can save the array by simply doing it like below:

```
$the_meta_array = array (
    'key-1' => 'value-1',
    'key-2' => 'value-2',
);  
$user_id = 12345;  
$user_meta_key = 'your-key';  
add_user_meta( $user_id, $user_meta_key, $the_meta_array );
```

Which is enough to save your array to the users meta data. `add_user_meta()` is just a wrapper for `add_metadata()`, the later uses `maybe_serialize()`, so your array will be saved as serialized string.

One more note about getting back the array you saved. You use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta), which is just a wrapper for `get_metadata()`, the later uses `maybe_unserialize()`, so an array will be returned. But you probably want to do this with `$single` set to `true` when retrieving the meta data later on. Because the default value of the `$single` parameter is `false`:

> **$single**
>       (boolean) (optional) If true return value of meta data field, if false return an array. This parameter has no effect if $key is left blank.
>   Default: false

```
$user_id = 12345;  
$user_meta_key = 'your-key'; 
$single = true;   
$retrieved_meta_array = get_user_meta( $user_id, $user_meta_key, $single );
```

If you don't use `true` you will get back your array wrapped inside an additional array, as above cite does suggest, which you are most likely don't want, because the array you saved is in this case actually the single value you want to return - ergo setting `$single` to `true` is the way to do it.